# Unable to invoke controller function from ng-dropdown-multiselect directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-dropdown-multiselect

I need to bind an event in my controller to be called when there is a change in value of a dropdown. This dropdown is a multi-select dropdown -which is in a directive.

I have been able to customize the dropdown using the settings available - however, unable to bind the event.

Here is the code 
HTML:

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>AngularJS Dropdown Multiselect</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

        <script src="./angular.min.js"></script>
        <!--<script src="./ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>-->
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.7.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
        <script src="./app.js"></script>
        <style>
            .noscroll {
                overflow: hidden;
            }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <div ng-dropdown-multiselect="" options="fruitdata"
         selected-model="fruitmodel" checkboxes="true"
         extra-settings="fruitsettings" events="extraEvents">
    </div>
    Selected Model: {{fruitmodel}} | json

</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
    'use strict';

var app = angular.module('myApp', ['angularjs-dropdown-multiselect']);

app.controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.fruitmodel = [];
    $scope.fruitsettings = {
        enableSearch: false
    };
    $scope.fruitdata = [{
        "label": "Apple",
            "id": 1
    }, {
        "label": "Banana",
            "id": 2
    }, {
        "label": "Orange",
            "id": 3
    }, {
        "label": "Pineapple",
            "id": 4
    }, {
        "label": "Strawberry",
            "id": 5
    }];
    $scope.example2settings = {
        displayProp: 'id'
    };

    $scope.extraEvents = {
        onItemDeselect: '$scope.onChange'
    };

    $scope.onChange = function() {
        console.log($scope.fruitdata);
    };
});
```

I need to detect the change to the model and take action based on this. I tried two approaches - adding ng-change to the dropdown as below - however, this does not work.

```
<div ng-dropdown-multiselect="" options="fruitdata"
     selected-model="fruitmodel" checkboxes="true"
     extra-settings="fruitsettings" ng-change="onChange()">
</div>
```

The directive does seem to allow extending the event handling - however, I guess I am not getting it right.

Comment: While this works fine - I realized that the code runs into issues related to event handling - when I click on "Deselect All", I get a call into my controller (asp.net controller called from Angular) with the value of the model having All values rather than 0 values as expected. I guess I need to handle this on blur - however, blur event does not get fired (I am using angularjs 1.3.15 which apparently does support blur).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Snapshot from **AngularJS Dropdown Multiselect**

[image]

Seems like you have to use:

```
<div ng-dropdown-multiselect="" ... events="eventsCallback"></div>
```

and into your controller:

```
$scope.eventsCallback = {
    onItemSelect:       function () { ... },
    onSelectionChanged: function () { ... }
}
```

Comment: While this works fine - I realized that the code runs into issues related to event handling - when I click on "Deselect All", I get a call into my controller (asp.net controller called from Angular) with the value of the model having All values rather than 0 values as expected. I guess I need to handle this on blur - however, blur event does not get fired (I am using angularjs 1.3.15 which apparently does support blur).

Answer (score 0):

Is $scope.fruitmodel where you are storing the selected items?  You can use $scope.$watchCollection to act on changes.

```
$scope.$watchCollection('fruitmodel', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    console.log(newValue, oldValue);
});
```

Comment: I think this will work - however, I prefer the approach Fabio Ruggiero provided.